# Processing object topology in prolog: finding bidirectional edges from list of triangles

Tags: prolog

Here's what I want to do.

Given the declaration:

```
vertex(v0, coord(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0)).
vertex(v1, coord(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)).
vertex(v2, coord(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)).
vertex(v3, coord(1.0, -1.0, 0.0)).

face(f0, v0, v1, v2).
face(f1, v0, v2, v3).

bidirEdge(A, B) :-
    edge(A, B),
    edge(B, A).
```

Run query `bidirEdge(X, Y).` and receive `X = v0, Y = v2; Y = v0, X = v2` as answer.

The declaration is topology of simple 3d quad :

```
 v0----v1
 | \ f0 |
 |  \   |
 |   \  |
 | f1 \ |
 v3----v2
```

where v0..v3 denote vertex indexes and f0..f1 denote faces.

How do I do that?

**What I already tried:**

I attempted to declare `face` as:

```
face(_, A, B, C) :-
    vertex(A, _),
    vertex(B, _),
    vertex(C, _),
    edge(A, B),
    edge(B, C),
    edge(C, A).
```

Straight off the bat, the query doesn't work, because prolog does not know what "edge" means.

If I try

```
edge(A, B) :-
    vertex(A, _),
    vertex(B, _).
```

or (not quite correct).

```
edge(A, B) :-
    vertex(A, _),
    vertex(B, _),
    A \== B.
```

That leads to amusing output.

```
63 ?- edge(X, Y).
X = Y, Y = v0 ;
X = v0,
Y = v1 ;
X = v0,
Y = v2 ;
X = v0,
Y = v3 ;
X = v1,
Y = v0 ;
X = Y, Y = v1 ;
X = v1,
Y = v2 ...
```

Basically, prolog "concludes" that "for all declared vertices, there is an edge connecting them" and lists all possible connections:

```
 v0--v1
 | \/ |
 | /\ |
 v3--v2
```

which pretty much ignores topology I provided and is not what I want.

I think that if I do something like this:

```
faceEdge(FaceID, A, B) :-
    belongsTo(FaceID, edge(A, B)).

face(FaceID, A, B, C) :-
    vertex(A, _),
    vertex(B, _),
    vertex(C, _),
    faceEdge(FaceID, A, B),
    faceEdge(FaceID, B, C),
    faceEdge(FaceID, C, A).
```

I should get required behavior, but I have no idea how to declare `belongsTo` (and have a hunch that's not how it should be done) and queries of this kind tend to cause infinite loops and hang my swi-prolog.

The main problem seems to be that I want prolog to determine list of edges for me without specifying it explicitly, which means that upon encountering "face(A, B, C)" it should treat it as seeral "edge()" statements and my declaration of "edge" is incorrect.

So, how do I correctly declare "edge" in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep it simple:

```
edge(X, Y) :- face(_, A, B, C), (X=A,Y=B ; X=B,Y=C ; X=C,Y=A).
```

and you'll get

```
?- bidirEdge(X,Y).
X = v2,
Y = v0 ;
X = v0,
Y = v2 ;
false.
```

the solution order doesn't match the requirement. Should be simple to change as required...

Comment: There is no requirement on solution order, anything would do as long as it can find bidirectional edges.

Comment: Tested it, it works. Thanks for the help/quick response.